# Problems using PyQt's Resource System

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to use PyQt's Resource System but it appears I have no clue what I am doing! I already have to application created, along with its GUI I am just trying to import some images to use with the program.

I used the QtDesigner to create the resource file and I compiled it using pyrcc4.exe. But when I attempt to import the resource file I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Projects\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    import main_rc
  File "C:\Projects\main_rc.py", line 482, in <module>
    qInitResources()
  File "C:\Projects\main_rc.py", line 477, in qInitResources
    QtCore.qRegisterResourceData(0x01, qt_resource_struct, qt_resource_name, qt_resource_data)
      TypeError: argument 2 of qRegisterResourceData() has an invalid type
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Smells like a possible mismatch between (designer and/or pyrcc4) and the PyQt4.x version. What specific platform and versions are you using?

Comment: I am using PyQt 4.6 on Python 3.1 all on Win7

Answer (score 19):

pyrcc generates Python 2.x code by default.

Try regenerating your resource files using pyrcc with flag '-py3'

Comment: Thanks, I was following the PySide tutorial and ran into this problem. Your answer was helpful to me.