# package a pyqt desktop application its resource file with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt, pyinstaller

I have created a desktop gui application which i want to package. I was directed to use pyinstaller to package it so i did. I have a mainwindow.py file where i import a resource file (converted to python code) as well as other imports going on in there. However when i run the output file,it gives me an error. I suspected it was due to my resource file, from the error so i tried pyinstaller on one of the modules and it worked perfectly. however i keep getting an error with the MainWindow.py file. I have the image of the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DVal.png) for your consideration. How do i go around this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem. After reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619574/problems-using-pyqts-resource-system), I tried pyrcc4 with the '-py3' flag and it worked. I think without the py3 flag,the resource file is converted into a python 2.x code. And I was trying to interpret py2 code with py3 interpreter. That's my understanding of the problem tho. But in case you  have a similar problem,try using the -'py3' flag for python3 interpreter.Good Luck